# Django - how to pass object to a template with a class based view?

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm switching over to class based views in my project for most of my views just because they are less repeated code, and I can't figure out how to pass an object to a template. By default using a detail view passes the object, which is fine for accessing direct attributes of it, but my objects have tags on them that are defined via an extension and accessed via a function  of that extension. In my old function based view, I would get the list of tags and pass it to the template like this to be iterated over:

```
  return render(request, "gallerypage.html", {
            'gallery': gallery,
            'tags': gallery.misc_tags.names(),
            'form': form
        })
```

My new view looks like this:

```
class GalleryView(DetailView):
    model = Gallery
    template_name = 'gallerypage.html'
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', GalleryView.as_view(), name='show_gallery'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', GalleryUpdate.as_view(), name='update_gallery',),
)
```

The gallery object is passed to the template fine, and I can access attributes of it, for example the name, by using something like `<h1>{{ object.name }}</h1>`.  But seeing as it isn't a good idea to try running arbitrary Python code in templates, I need a better way to pass the tags object into the template so I can display them, as something like

{`{ object.misc_tags.names()|join:", " }}`

right in it will not work. Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't `object.misc_tags.names` without the parens implicitly call the function? Alternatively `get_context_data`

Comment: Ah, that works well, no overriding needed. Thank you.

Comment: turned that into an answer for you. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

You could override [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data) and add any additional context you want. This method is often overriden in CBV's

Answer (score 1):

Calling `object.misc_tags.names` without the parentheses would implicitly call the function. Alternatively use `get_context_data` like dm03514 had suggested.

From the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#variables) on periods in templates:

> Technically, when the template system encounters a dot, it tries the following lookups, in this order:
>
> - Dictionary lookup
> - Attribute lookup
> - Method call
> - List-index lookup